# Apache CloudStack + OVH Bare Metal

Tags: cloud, infrastructure, provisioning, cloudstack

I am new in the world of IaaS & provisioning and I'm blocked with Apache CloudStack.

We currently have a few Bare Metal Dedicated servers with OVH running Ubuntu 22 with KVM installed on it for virtualization. Each server has a public IPv4 address and an IPv6 address range. The goal is to use [Apache CloudStack](https://cloudstack.apache.org/) to manage the infrastructure, so we can add more bare metal servers and create VMs as needed.

Following the [documentation](https://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/en/4.18.1.0/), I have installed an Apache CloudStack management server. Regarding the information on the [form to create a new Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKJig.png):

1. What value should I use for IPv4 DNS1? As the bare metal server has a public IPv4 addr, will DNS 1.1.1.1 be good?

The "Internal DNS 1", I understand it is to identify the different VMs that will be created on the Bare Metal server, therefore, I must have something like [Ubuntu DNS](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-domain-name-service-dns) to resolve those.

2. Is this the right approach?

The network configuration of the zone requires a Gateway, Netmask, IPv4 range and VLAN/VNI. Because the Bare Metal servers have only one IPv4 addr by default, that would be my "IPv4 range" for public traffic. The Gateway and Netmask values will be the same as I can see from *ifconfig* command.

3. Is this reasoning right?

On the PODs creation, the "Reserved system IP/Netmask/Gateway" refer to internal addresses that I can choose to design our internal network without public visibility.

4. Is this correct?

Thanks for your help!